# conda not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, anaconda, conda

I've installed Anaconda and now I want to create a conda environment,

```
C:> conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
```

but then I get the error that "**conda**" is **not recognized** as an internal or external command.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

As Windows user you have to start a **Anaconda Prompt** from the start menu. Look in your start menu for anaconda3-64bit -> anaconda prompt.
Now the `conda` command should be found in this shell.

Otherwise add the Anaconda Binaries folder to your environment path.